# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed : MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Session Table is here:**

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**User Table is below**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblusers` (
  `UserID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `EmailAddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RoleID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
```

**I tried below query to apply Foreign Key Constraint in Sessions Table**

```
ALTER TABLE sessions
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_sessions_tblusers_UserID
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES tblusers(UserID)
```

**MySQL says**

> 1005 - Can't create table `myapp`.`#sql-6b8_83` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed")

**Question**

Am I missing something ?

Comment: try adding an index on sessions.userid first

Comment: After adding the index, still same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the column types of `sessions.user_id` and `tblusers.UserID` don't quite match. I reproduced the same error and fixed it by altering the two columns as follows...

```
`user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
```

...and...

```
`UserID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

The foreign key was successfully created after I made those changes. Note that I didn't have to change the nullability to match, though you may want to do this with `sessions.user_id` if a session is required to have a user id...

```
`user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Comment: value of `user_id` can be null in `Sessions` table.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Just disregard the last part of my answer since it doesn't apply to your application. Others may find it useful.